# Is there any way of detecting the ending of flood_fill recursive method with return type void?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, recursion

As the question suggest, I implementing a recursive function with return type of "void" (the function is similar to the game "Flood it!", here's a link for the game https://unixpapa.com/floodit/).

So each time the function FloodFill() is called within a GameObject, it changed its own color, and, if the adjacent tiles to it are within a range of condition, it activated those adjacent tiles FloodFill() function.

The problem is, I want to activate other functions when the recursive method is finished, but as the return type is void, I don't know when it will end, and as it's similar to a "procedure" instead of the "function", the "hook" (the conditions for the recursion to end and turn back) of the recursive method is more or less vague.

In most case you can check if the recursion is finished by checking the "hook" again. If the conditions is true for the top-layer recursive call (the first call of the recursive function), then recursion is finished.

I try to solve the problem by changing the return type of FloodIt() to bool and change StartFloodIt() - the function that start the whole cascade of recursion - to become a coroutine. 
Then I used this to became the yeild condition:

```
yeild return new WaitUntil(() => FloodIt());
```

Here's the StartFloodFill() function:

```
IEnumerator StartFloodFill()
{
    DisableButtons();
    var a = false;
    a = gms.FloodFill(0, 0, GetComponent<Image>().color, gms.tilesColorArray[0, 0]);
    yield return new WaitUntil(a);
    EnableButttons();
}
```

And here's the FloodFill() function that's recursive:

```
public bool FloodFill(int x, int y, Color targetColor, Color prevColor) 
{
    if (x < 0 || x >= totalRows || y < 0 || y >= totalRows || tilesColorArray[x, y] != prevColor) // the "hook" condition
    {
        return true;
    }

    tilesColorArray[x, y] = targetColor;

    //calling recursively to adjacent tile
    FloodFill(x, y - 1, targetColor, prevColor);
    FloodFill(x, y + 1, targetColor, prevColor);
    FloodFill(x - 1, y, targetColor, prevColor);
    FloodFill(x + 1, y, targetColor, prevColor);

    return true;
}
```

The system return me with the error that it

> "cannot convert from 'bool' to System.Func"

So it indicated that this approach more or less failed. 
Any ideas about different solutions? Or a fix of the above code snippet?

If you need more info, please ask me in the comment section.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [WaitUntil](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/WaitUntil.html) accepts a delegate as argument, but you are passing the `bool` that is returned from `FloodFill` instead, you should be able to fix the error by invoking `WaitUntil` like:

```
yield return new WaitUntil(() => gms.FloodFill(0, 0, GetComponent<Image>().color, gms.tilesColorArray[0, 0]));
```

Comment: But now then the program stopped working altogether... It doesn't have any more errors though

Comment: If you are placing [Debug.Log("your message")](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Debug.Log.html) statements in your methods you should be able to follow the behavior of your app in the [Console](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Console.html).